# Mockito test case failing

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito

I work with mvp pattern and treid to test short presenter method

This is

```
final public void setOriginPreviewImage() {
final String path = model.getImageFilePath();
iActivityAcceptNotAccept.setPreviewImage(path);
}
```

This method retrieves the path and pass it via interface to view

This is test

```
public class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest {

private PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept presenter;

@Mock ModelAcceptNotAccept model;
@Mock IActivityAcceptNotAccept iActivityAcceptNotAccept;

@Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    presenter = new PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept(iActivityAcceptNotAccept);
}

@Test public void setOriginPreviewImage() throws Exception {
    presenter.setOriginPreviewImage();
    when(model.getImageFilePath()).thenReturn("path");
    String path = model.getImageFilePath();
    verify(iActivityAcceptNotAccept).setPreviewImage(path);
}
```

here in the first line I invoke the method, then do `when()` to point that if `getImageFilePath()` will been invoke then return `"path"` as a value.

In the third line I invoke `getImageFilePath()` I expect to get valeu that I had set up prior to this line - `"path"`.

But instead of this I get such error

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.tools.cameraTools.ImageSaver.getImageFilePath(ImageSaver.java:37)
>       at com.fittingroom.newtimezone.model.ModelAcceptNotAccept.getImageFilePath(ModelAcceptNotAccept.java:14)

I get the error during processing `model.getImageFilePath();`

according to the log file test don't return back the value that I had set up hire

```
when(model.getImageFilePath()).thenReturn("path");
```

instead of this it is trying to get value from the method, of course there is no value because it is test...

How model assosiated with presenter

```
public final class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept implements IPresenterAcceptNotAccept {
private IActivityAcceptNotAccept iActivityAcceptNotAccept;
private ModelAcceptNotAccept model;

public PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept(IActivityAcceptNotAccept iActivityAcceptNotAccept) {
    this.iActivityAcceptNotAccept = iActivityAcceptNotAccept;
    this.model = new ModelAcceptNotAccept(this);
}
```

Model code

```
public class ModelAcceptNotAccept {
private IPresenterAcceptNotAccept iPresenterAcceptNotAccept;

public ModelAcceptNotAccept(IPresenterAcceptNotAccept iPresenterAcceptNotAccept) {
    this.iPresenterAcceptNotAccept = iPresenterAcceptNotAccept;
}

public String getImageFilePath(){
    return ImageSaver.getImageFilePath();
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

```
@Test public void setOriginPreviewImage() throws Exception {
    //when(model.getImageFilePath()).thenReturn("path");
    doReturn("path").when(model.getImageFilePath());
    presenter.setOriginPreviewImage();
    String path = model.getImageFilePath();
    verify(iActivityAcceptNotAccept).setPreviewImage(path);
}
```

give me such errors

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at   com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTes t.setOriginPreviewImage(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest.java:30)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
1. missing thenReturn()
2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed


 at   com.fittingroom.newtimezone.presenters.PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest.setOriginPreviewImage(PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

**EDIT2**

[image]

**EDIT3**

My test now

```
@Test public void setOriginPreviewImage() throws Exception {
    presenter.setOriginPreviewImage();
    doReturn("path").when(model).getImageFilePath();
    String path = model.getImageFilePath();
    verify(contractAcceptNotAccept).setPreviewImage(path);
}
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your most recent update, bear in mind that `doVerb().when()` syntax is different: Unlike `when().thenVerb()` syntax, you don't put the whole method call inside the `when` argument, just the mock in question.

```
/*  BAD */ doReturn("path").when(model.getImageFilePath());
//                                    v- see the parens -^
/* GOOD */ doReturn("path").when(model).getImageFilePath();
```

You're getting that message because the `doReturn` syntax starts to prepare a custom object for you--one that has all of its stubbing disabled--and rather than calling `when` and then calling a method on the proxy object returned by `when(model)`, you call a method on the original mock `model`. The stubbing action isn't finished the way Mockito would like it to be, so Mockito throws an UnfinishedStubbingException.

Comment: yes really it looks like correct, but anyway I get error. Not the same as was but I don't have any assumption why... It looks like `doReturn()` method doesn't work correctly. I added new screenshot to question `EDIT3`

Comment: I found mistake)) this line `doReturn("path").when(model).getImageFilePath();` has to be the first line in test method) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code:

(1) Add `@InjectMocks` in order to inject the mock objects to the `PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept` class

(2) Mock the methods calls (of `@Mock` objects) first before calling the actual methods.

(3) Use `doNothing()` to mock the `void` returning method calls

```
public class PresenterActivityAcceptNotAcceptTest {

   @InjectMocks
   private PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept presenter;

   @Mock ModelAcceptNotAccept model;
   @Mock IActivityAcceptNotAccept iActivityAcceptNotAccept;

    @Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       presenter = new PresenterActivityAcceptNotAccept(iActivityAcceptNotAccept);
   }

    @Test public void setOriginPreviewImage() throws Exception {
        //mock the method call
        when(model.getImageFilePath()).thenReturn("path");

        //doNothing for void call
        doNothing().when(iActivityAcceptNotAccept).setPreviewImage("path");


        //verify the method call
        verify(iActivityAcceptNotAccept).setPreviewImage("path");
    }

}
```

You can look [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/mockito/mockito-mock-void-method-call/) for sample tests on how to use Mockito.

Comment: Look at the updated answer, you have few issues with Test method

Comment: I added screenshot to question with result... It said that I need to add `thenReturn` in 39 line, but when I try to add `.thenReturn()` studio said that there is no such method

Comment: look at the answer above, it should be doNothing().when(iActivityAcceptNotAccept).setPreviewImage("path");

Comment: and eventually I get the same error as I get in the beginer. I mentioned this error at the beginer of my question `java.lang.NullPointerException at `

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mockito.doReturn(...).when(...);` since this won't call the mocked method and returns the mock value immediately.

Comment: I have tried to do it ... I added result in question... I am not sure that it is correct way